# Why i can't call method in subscribe - Cannot read property 'showMessageFromSocket' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want call method in subscribe block, but I got "Cannot read property 'showMessageFromSocket' of undefined". How can I call method showMessageFromSocket? In angular it was possible.

```
export default class ConnectedChatroom extends Component<
  ConnectedChatroomProps,
  ConnectedChatroomState
> {
  wsObj: CompatClient;

  constructor(props: Props, context: *) {
    super(props, context);
    this.configureSocketChannel('dassfa')
  }

  showMessageFromSocket(message)  {
    console.log(message);
    //do something
  }

  configureSocketChannel(senderId: string) {
    let ws = Stomp.client("ws://localhost:8080/chat");
    ws.connect({}, function (frame) {
      ws.subscribe("/topic/messages", function (message) {
        this.showMessageFromSocket(message);
      });
    }, function (error) {
      console.log("STOMP error " + error);
    });
    this.wsObj = ws;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `arrow` function to access class members like variable or method of class without self variable.

Try like below

```
configureSocketChannel(senderId: string) {
    let ws = Stomp.client("ws://localhost:8080/chat");
    ws.connect({},  (frame) => {
      ws.subscribe("/topic/messages",  (message) => {
        this.showMessageFromSocket(message);
      });
    }, function (error) {
      console.log("STOMP error " + error);
    });
    this.wsObj = ws;
}
```